# Grouping a View by Taxonomy term with multiple values without listing the term more than once

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How do I stop a Taxonomy vocabulary's terms being listed multiple times when I group a view's results by Taxonomy term and instead list the content type multiple times under single terms.

For example, this setup...

[image: view configuration with taxonomy terms]

Produces this result...

[image: view display (current)]

Whereas what I need is it to produce a result like this... (I might have mixed up some of the categories, I did use Paint after all)

[image]

To explain the context: I have a view that lists all 'clients' that have registered to us (I have used a custom Content Type 'Client', Node Limit module and custom permissions/roles ('Client') to have a 'Client' node double as a pseudo person/business.

I have used the Taxonomy module to create a 'Clients categories' vocabulary. The terms in this vocabulary categorise Clients, however Clients **may** exist in more than one category and so a real-life client **may** check multiple checkboxes of these terms. So I have setup the content type Client's 'Number of Values' as 'Unlimited'.

### The view (exported)

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'Clients_index';
$view->description = 'Page view showing all Clients';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Clients Index';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Clients Index';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'domain';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['domains'] = array(
  1 => 0,
  2 => '2',
  3 => '3',
  4 => '4',
);
$handler->display->display_options['access']['domain_strict'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['domain_member'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'term_node_tid',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'Clients' => 'Clients',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = '<h2 class="block-title">Clients\' directory</h2>
<p>Welcome to the Clients\' . Here you can find a relevant Client by product category or by name, or search for a specific company using the search box.</p>';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'full_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['empty'] = FALSE;
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = '<p>To register as a Client, please contact us</p>';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'full_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: All taxonomy terms */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['id'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['field'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['limit'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['term_node_tid']['vocabularies'] = array(
  'Clients_categories' => 'Clients_categories',
  'tags' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'Clients';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Clients';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['description'] = 'Clients\' directory';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '-47';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is from Szerge who posted on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1239278#comment-6583454). I have added one more relevant step.

1. Create a *Content: Taxonomy terms on node* relationship (which is well explained in different posts like https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1239278#comment-5515924)
2. Display a field with the
   *taxonomy term: (term) Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term* (and     the field containing the taxonomy terms with MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS
   "Display all values in the same row" unchecked)
3. Add the *(term) Taxonomy term: Name (asc)* sort criteria
4. Lastly, ensure your "Format" format settings for the entire view are grouped in *Grouping field Nr.1* according to the *taxonomy term: (term) Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term*

Comment: I've not checked this, but my original answer was a workaround so this is a better first option to check out for future visitors

Comment: Thank you for setting my answer as the answer, and @kiamlaluno for editing.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I created a View of Taxonomy terms based on the above requirements, I then (at least first off, to get it done quickly) created a [Views template](https://drupal.org/node/355664) specific to this (and only this) purpose.

In that template I added code after the printing of the terms that loaded the node title by taking the term id from the `$row` variable. Using `db_select()` on the `taxonomy_index` table to get the associated node ids (`nid`). I then Used `$node = node_load($nid)` to load the node and get the title `$node->title`. I have clean URLs and Pathauto installed so I had to hardcode the `/clients` portion of the required URL and passed `$node->title` through a Pathauto function `pathauto_cleanstring()` to create the alias path. Finally I used `url()` and `l()` as described in [this article](http://edmedia.net.au/content/creating-links-drupal-7-using-url-and-l).

For the most part I followed [this process](http://www.jahimandahalf.co.uk/using-pathauto-functions-in-a-block-to-create-lists-of-taxonomy-terms-and-their-associated-nodes-content-with-a-custom-content-type-where-one-node-could-have-multiple-terms) but it's a very specific implementation so others might not want to follow it as a tutorial.