# Group view by term without listing terms multiple times

Tags: views

I have a view of nodes where the nodes have terms that I want to group them by, but I want to list each term only once and have any node that has multiple terms, listed under each appropriate group. What I have been able to do is group the view by term, but if a node has multiple terms, I get a group that has both terms listed. For example, this is the results I'm getting currently:

- Term 1
  - node1
  - node2
- Term 2
  - node3
  - node4
- Term 1, Term2
  - node5

I need it to look like:

- Term 1
  - node1
  - node2
  - node5
- Term 2
  - node3
  - node4
  - node5

Is there an easier way to accomplish this besides this: [Grouping a View by Taxonomy term with multiple values without listing the term more than once](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/grouping-a-view-by-taxonomy-term-with-multiple-values-without-listing-the-term-m)

This seems like the same problem I'm having, but I'm not experienced enough to understand this solution.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2086611#comment-7854997

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546771/787529